# Getting rid of commas in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my program:

```
def Prob2( rows, columns ):
for i in range(1, rows+1):
    print(list(range(i, (columns*i)+1, i)))


Prob2( rows = int(input("Enter number of rows here: ")), columns = int(input("Enter number of columns here: ")))
```

Essentially, it takes a user input of rows and columns and, based on those inputs, makes lists of multiples starting with 1.

For example, if the user typed in 4 rows and 5 columns, the program would output something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
```

The problem I have is that I need to get rid of the commas and only have spaces between the numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: You can convert the list to a string and call str.replace(‘,’, ‘’) before you print it.

Comment: `print(' '.join(str(x) for x in range(i, (columns*i)+1, i)))`.

Comment: There are a million duplicates of this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your title specifies :

> Getting rid of commas in a list

I'll give the general version of it.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> s = ' '.join(str(x) for x in l)
>>> s
'1 2 3 4'
```

Here since the list contains `int`, we use list comprehension to convert each individual into `str` before joining.

Suppose the list contained `str`, we can directly do :

```
>>> l = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> l
['1', '2', '3', '4']

>>> s = ' '.join(l)
>>> s
'1 2 3 4'
```

Comment: Sure, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Could just convert your lists to strings and remove your commas with the re.sub() method.

```
import re


def Prob2(rows, columns):
    for i in range(1, rows + 1):
        numbers = re.sub(",", "", str(range(i, (columns * i) + 1, i)))
        print(numbers)


Prob2(rows=int(input("Enter number of rows here: ")),
      columns=int(input("Enter number of columns here: ")))
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 4 6 8 10]
[3 6 9 12 15]
[4 8 12 16 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
def Prob2( rows, columns ):
    for i in range(1, rows+1):
        print('['+', '.join(map(str, list(range(i, (columns*i)+1, i))))+']')


Prob2( rows = int(input("Enter number of rows here: ")), columns = int(input("Enter number of columns here: ")))
```

Using `' '.join()` is a trick that allows you to convert a list to a string where `map(str, <list>)` iterates over each value in that list and apply the `str()` function on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Prob2( rows, columns ):
    for i in range(1, rows+1):
        print('['+' '.join(str(val) for val in range(i, (columns*i)+1, i))+']')

Prob2( rows = int(input("Enter number of rows here: ")), columns = int(input("Enter number of columns here: ")))
```

output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 4 6 8 10]
[3 6 9 12 15]
[4 8 12 16 20]
```